# Low-latency variable sharing between Matlab sessions?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I have a script that starts a Matlab timer object, as well as a presentation toolbox. The presentation toolbox seems quite taxing on the computer or Matlab, so the timer object does not run 'on time' (it's setup to look for new files, but only catches every couple new files - when the presentation toolbox is not running, it's smooth). I would like to try and solve this by running two separate Matlab sessions, but I am unsure how I can have low-latency variable sharing between the two sessions (the timer object processes data, and the presentation software uses it). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of options:

- You can use a pipe shared between the two matlab sessions (if you're running on a POSIX-like system).
- You can use PNET or the Instrument Control Toolbox (ICT) to communicate over local network sockets. The advantage of using ICT is that it has an asynchronous interface -- you get to define a callback function which is called when data is available. PNET requires a polling loop.
- Assuming both processes are running on the same (POSIX-like) system, you can use [shared memory](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28572-sharedmatrix) to link two matlab sessions. The issue then will be synchronisation.